# Most seamless technique for TDD / Testing

Tags: python, testing, tdd, pytest

Ive just discovered Test Driven developement and I really like to the looks of it and want to start, however there seems to be one main problem in my mind. Unlike most other negative comments I see in regards to it such as it is slow to start or adds extra time etc. (I disagree with these points). My issue is that it seems very....clunky.

This is what I mean.

If I were to write a test (Using python and pytest)

```
def multiply_3_4():
    answer = 3 * 4
    assert answer == 12
```

You write the empty test and make it fail as its empty. Then you fill in the code to make it pass.

But then my problem is, OK so you have working code now so then you copy and paste the working code block from the test function into your main programme? You make some changes and you copy that section back into the test function to retest it to make sure you have not broken anything and copy back again into the main programme etc?

It seems to me a bit disjointed / clunky or un-seamless. Is there not a way where you have your tests linked into your application code such as having labels such as

```
# Test 1 starts here
code
code
code
# Test 1 ends here
```

Then the test function would just see this and run a test using that block of code making it more of a seamless experience.

Not prone to copy and pasting errors or messing about of copying code between files and test functions etc.

So my question is, is what im saying correct? Or is there a specific type of workflow to go between tests and the actual application code in a more elegant / seamless manner?

This is the only thing holding me back from TDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test file:

```
import myprog

def test_multiply():
    answer = myprog.multiply()
    assert answer == 12
```

In myprog.py:

```
def multiply():
    return 3*4
```

There should be no copy-pasting. Just import.

At any stage you should be able to just run your unit tests and it should give you feed back on what parts of your program is working or needs work.

---

To make your program both importable and runnable you could write your program with this general structure:

```
<import statements>
define CONSTANTS
Class and function definitions
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `if __name__ == '__main__':` suite will be executed when the program is run, but not when the program qua *module* is imported.
Thus, there need not be any code hanging out at the module level which is not testable.

Comment: So that means that every line of code I write would need to be enclosed in a function or class or method of some kind?

Comment: Only things that can be imported should be tested (So yes, that is mostly functions and class methods, and possible module globals). That is the interface the module provides. Test what the module does, not how it is implemented. That way, you have the freedom to change your implementation, and know the change is possibly correct as long as it still passes the tests.

Comment: This is just me thinking allowed but, what about the code that goes inbetween? Bits that go in between function calls and objects etc, the "glue" code?.......Maybe if this code is becoming to much its a sign it should be a function for example?

Comment: Does it need to be tested? If so, put it in a function.

Comment: @Binarysmacker: you have integration tests for testing the integration between units (modules, functions). Unit Testing is for the units.

Answer (score 0):

Some addition to that, there a techique called [TDD as you mean it](http://coderetreat.org/facilitating/activities/tdd-as-if-you-meant-it), that follows something you tried to use.

You write the code and test in the same file and after you got *green* state, just move the code the the actual place it should be.

I've tried that and sometimes it works fine, especially if I just want to try something quickly. With modern IDE's and refactoring tools it's rather easy to move the code to another method or class.

But as you just starting with TDD, please don't bother with that :) stick to classic rules!